# Rails Tutorial - Not understanding implementation of follow/unfollow users in Chap 11

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

My main difficulty comes from understanding the relationship that the `_follow` and `_unfollow` partials have with the `create` and `destroy` methods defined in the `RelationshipsController` from [Chapter 11.2.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#sec-following_and_followers_pages).  I'll just focus on the act of **unfollowing** a user for now (since the act of following is mostly analogous).

Hartl defines the partial for `unfollow` as such:

```
<%= form_for(current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user), html: { method: :delete }) do |f| %> 
    <%= f.submit "Unfollow", class: "btn btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

and the corresponding `destroy` action as such:

```
def destroy
    @user = Relationship.find(params[:id]).followed
    current_user.unfollow!(@user)
    redirect_to @user
end
```

What I am having trouble understanding is:

1. The `@user` variable in the first line of the `unfollow` partial .. is this **a)** defined in the `show` action that currently displays the page, *or* **b)** defined in the `destroy` action?  It appears that the `form_for` helper already finds the `@user` to be destroyed, so why does the `destroy` action needs to find the `@user` all over again to be destroyed in the controller?
2. In the `destroy` method, the `@user` is found by first finding the Relationship id.  I don't see how the Relationship id is passed into the URI in the first place (since seeing a particular user to unfollow shows up as `/users/2`), much less how it is used to find the `@user` to destroy.  I understand that each Relationship table has an id, a followed_id, and a follower_id, but do not see how the id element itself comes into play here.

Thanks, for reading, and for answering my questions!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) If the partial is rendered within the `show` action, the variable @user must be defined in that action. Rails won't execute the `destroy` method so the variable definition in there will never be executed.

Since HTTP is a stateless protocol, the server needs to create the necessary state on every request. That's why @user must be defined in every action.

2.) Where did you check that the url is "/users/2"? As I don't see the whole code I can only make guesses but the following line `current_user.relationships.find_by_followed_id(@user)` should return a `Relationship` object. It will be translated into something like "/relationships/8", where 8 is the ID of the `Relationship`. Because you specify `method: :delete, the destroy action will be invoked.

I think the url "/users/2" is after the destroy action performed the deletion was performed. There could be a redirect in the destroy action. (eg. `redirect_to current_user`). You can see all the invoked actions in the log file. Try scrolling through the log and see if you can find `RelationshipsController#destroy`. You will see the invoked url there. Also you could inspect the HTML to see where the `<form>` tag's "action" attribute points to.

Comment: This all makes so much more sense now.. especially your answer in part 2.  I commented out the `create` and `destroy` functions and indeed it showed the URL as "relationships/1".  I should have realized that `current_user.RELATIONSHIPS.find_by_followed_id(@user)` would have returned a relationship, thus fitting neatly into the puzzle piece.  Thanks again!